# Groovy static compilation

Tags: groovy, static-compilation

1. Can I write 100% static code using groovy? even if I am using standard libs?
2. How do I enable 100% static compilation application wide?

Comment: http://www.jroller.com/melix/entry/static_type_checking_talk_from

Comment: I think this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074219/static-compile-groovy-by-default-using-maven.