# Static compile .groovy by default using maven

Tags: maven, groovy

I am now using maven to compile .groovy in our project

my pom.xml is

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <configscript>/tmp/aa.groovy</configscript>
                </compilerArguments>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.0-01</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Is there something like

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Advanced+compiler+configuration

groovyc -configscript src/conf/config.groovy src/main/groovy/MyClass.groovy

so I can compile my groovy in a static way by default

Comment: Nothing available now. Best thing to do is to annotate all relevant classes with @CompileStatic

Comment: requested on greclipse http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-1615

Answer (score 2):

You may use Ant

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <mkdir dir="${basedir}/src/main/groovy"/>
                            <taskdef name="groovyc" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc">
                                <classpath refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                            </taskdef>
                            <mkdir dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
                            <groovyc destdir="${project.build.outputDirectory}" 
                                     srcdir="${basedir}/src/main/groovy/" 
                                     listfiles="true"
                                     configscript="${basedir}/src/config/config.groovy">
                                <classpath refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                            </groovyc>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And config.groovy

```
withConfig(configuration) {
   ast(groovy.transform.CompileStatic)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm resurrecting a bit of an old thread here, but I ran across your question and thought it'd be really cool if we did that in GMavenPlus, so I opened a [Jira](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GMAVENPLUS-10) and started messing around with it.  I've [committed](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/commit/e557ff0e6a6b928a5d84bc9179d3d0262d82af00) the first pass at this functionality, I'd appreciate it if you could test it out before our next release.  I've deployed a new [snapshot](https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/codehaus/gmavenplus/gmavenplus-plugin/1.1-SNAPSHOT/) for your convenience.