# @CompileStatic used on plain Groovy scripts

Tags: groovy

I'm not sure if this is already possible but is it possible to use @CompileStatic on just plain groovy scripts without wrapping the script in a class?

I'm using the GroovyClassLoader to parse and compile scripts dynamically and so it would be nice if scripts could use @CompileStatic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a [compiler customizer](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2016/01/groovy-goodness-customising-groovy.html):

```
configuration.addCompilationCustomizers(
    new ASTTransformationCustomizer(CompileStatic))
```

---

If you were on the command line you could provide a `--configscript config.groovy`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17996548/563890) has an example of how the script should look like:

```
withConfig(configuration) {
    ast(groovy.transform.CompileStatic)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the **@CompileStatic** annotation  to a class or a method.

It does not work for a whole script but you can add it to some methods or some classes of your script.

You have to add the **import groovy.transform.CompileStatic** in the imports of your script or class.

As an example you can try the following script in a GroovyConsole,  commenting/uncommenting the method annotation:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic


@CompileStatic
void loop() {
    def d1 = new Date();

    int[] t = new int[32*1024*1024]
    (0 .. 32*1024*1024-1).each { 
        it -> t[it] = it
        }

    def d2 = new Date();

    println d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()
}

loop()
```